# how to get value of Refernce ID from the same table?

Tags: mysql

I  am having a Employee table where I have Employee Number, reporting ID,Emp.Name etc. I am storing Emp.No in the Reporting ID column. Now I want to display Employee Name not their reporting IDs of a particular Employee. I tried few things but its not working well.

This is my code

```
SELECT  Distinct
hma.First_Name as Reporting1,
hmaa.First_Name as Reporting2,
hmaaa.First_Name as Reporting3,
hmaaaa.First_Name as Reviewer
from  abc hm
left join abc hma on hm.Employee_Number=hma.Reporting1
left join abc hmaa on hma.Employee_Number=hmaa.Reporting2
left join abc hmaaa on hmaa.Employee_Number=hmaaa.Reporting3
left join abc hmaaaa on hmaaa.Employee_Number=hmaaaa.Reviewer
where hmaaa.Employee_Number=97876757
Group by Reporting1,Reporting2,Reporting3,Reviewer;
```

Comment: Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Hiii..Now,i am getting the result in the form of Reporter1,Reporter2,

Comment: i want this query data  colomn wise in mysql query not row wise.How should i do that?